Monaco editor with Angular V18 - Custom theme
I think I am missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out and it gets frustrating...
What I try to do: Implement a Monaco editor in an Angular V18 application to insert C# code. Can't be that difficult, since I have seen it on other websites so many times. Sadly, the truth is different.
Since Monaco doesn't have a C# IntelliSense by default I learned there are different ways. On of them is a language server... Not in the mood for that now, so I want to add a custom theme with some keywords defined in Angular. There are tons of examples, but none of them seem to be working on my machine.
This is my app.module.ts:
    monaco.languages.register({ id: 'csharp' });

// Set Monarch tokenization rules for C# language
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('csharp', {
  keywords: ['public', 'void', 'if', 'else', 'for', 'while', 'return', 'using'],
  typeKeywords: ['Console', 'string', 'int', 'bool', 'double'],
  operators: ['=', '>', '<', '!', '==', '!=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '&&', '||'],
  symbols: /[=><!~?:&|+\-*\/\^%]+/,
  tokenizer: {
    root: [
      // Match identifiers
      [/[A-Z][\w$]*/, {
        cases: {
          '@typeKeywords': 'type',    // Types like Console (green)
          '@default': 'identifier'    // Other identifiers
        }
      }],
      // Match keywords
      [/[a-zA-Z_]\w*/, {
        cases: {
          '@keywords': 'keyword',     // C# keywords (blue)
          'hello': 'helloToken',      // Custom token for "hello"
          '@default': 'identifier'    // Default identifier
        }
      }],
      // Recognize strings
      [/".*"/, 'string'],
      // Match brackets, operators, etc.
      [/[{}()\[\]]/, '@brackets'],
      [/@symbols/, { cases: { '@operators': 'operator' } }]
    ]
  }
});

export const customTheme: monaco.editor.IStandaloneThemeData = {
  base: 'vs-dark',
  inherit: true,
  rules: [
    { token: '', foreground: '2A2C2D' },
    { token: 'hello', foreground: '#66ff66' },
    { token: 'string.key.json', foreground: '7b3814' },
    { token: 'string.value.json', foreground: '0F6980', fontStyle: 'bold' }
  ],
  colors: {
    'editor.background': '#ff0000',
    'editor.lineHighlightBackground': '#ff0000',
    'editorCursor.foreground': '#ff0000',
    'editor.selectionBackground': '#ff0000',
    'editor.inactiveSelectionBackground': '#ff0000',
  }
};


const monacoConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
  baseUrl: 'assets', // configure base path for monaco editor. Starting with version 8.0.0 it defaults to './assets'. Previous releases default to '/assets'
  defaultOptions: { scrollBeyondLastLine: false }, // pass default options to be used
  onMonacoLoad: () => {
    monaco.editor.defineTheme('customTheme', customTheme);
  },
  monacoRequire: (<any>window).monacoRequire,
  requireConfig: { preferScriptTags: true }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MonacoEditorModule.forRoot(monacoConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

My app.component.ts:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'monaco-test4';

  editorOptions = { theme: 'customTheme', language: 'csharp' };
  code: string = `public void x() {
    Console.WriteLine("hello world");
    hello; // This should be highlighted
  }`;
}

and the app.component.html:
<div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <ngx-monaco-editor
      [options]="editorOptions"
      [(ngModel)]="code"
      style="flex: 1; margin-top: 20px;"
    ></ngx-monaco-editor>
  </div>

I tried to load the customTheme and make the word 'hello' green. But no matter what I do, it stays black. Changing other colors don't do much either.
What I tried to do:

Search stack overflow
Ask ChatGPT (that was a nightmare! Why do people 'love' this??)
Read different blogs
Scream at my laptop

What am I doing wrong?

I had the same problem. It seems you need to register the theme not from the monaco-editor import, but this way:
    declare let monaco: any;
   
    export const monacoCustomLanguageConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
        onMonacoLoad: monacoCustomLanguagesLoad
    }

    export function monacoCustomLanguagesLoad() {
        monaco.languages.register({id: ‘csharp’});
        monaco.editor.defineTheme(‘csharpTheme’, yourCSharpTheme);
        monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider(‘csharp’, yourCsharpSyntaxLanguage);
    }

